The pictures taken are not getting saved in the folder but its creating a different folder but the images are not saved in it
Im trying to build a Sign language detector but when I take images to label the image folders are created but images are not stored in it.
Images_path = 'Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages'

for label in labels:
    !mkdir {'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages\\'+label}
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label))
    time.sleep(5)

    for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        imagename = os.path.join(Images_path, label, label + '.' + str(uuid.uuid1()) + '.jpg')
        cv2.imwrite(imagename, frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        time.sleep(2)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()

The image are supposed to be saved in collected images folder but new folders are created but the

[tour], [ask], [mre]
